# Change the size of the "format" drop down menu in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I would like to change the size of "format" drop down menu (select) in CKEditor. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: I am looking at the code - it seems there is not config setting for this and several CSS declarations would need to be overwritten, starting from "cke_styles_panel". Because this uses an IFrame for this dialog it's a bit of a pain to trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the `.cke_format_panel` class styles. Use `!important` just to be sure:

```
.cke_format_panel
{
    height: 250px !important;
}
```

Comment: This works with current Chrome but not with current Firefox

Answer (score 2):

I'm using CKEditor 4 and the following classes are assigned to the **format** menu:

```
cke cke_reset_all cke_1 cke_panel cke_combopanel cke_ltr
```

and the **styles** menu has:

```
cke cke_reset_all cke_1 cke_panel cke_combopanel cke_ltr cke_combopanel__styles
```

So you'll need to use `cke_panel` or `cke_combopanel` but this will also affect the **styles** menu, but you can then override them again with **cke_combopanel__styles**:

```
.cke_combopanel {
     width: 250px !important;
}
.cke_combopanel__styles {
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

**Note:** The css must go into your main document's styles and *not* the CKEditor's styles. This is because the classes are assigned to divs which wrap the iframes containing the menus, and not within the iframes themselves, where the CKEditor styles are loaded.